# How to determine which dijit.layout.AccordionPane is currently selected

Tags: dojo, accordionpane

I tried to use "dijit.layout.AccordionPane.selected" to determine if any given AccordionPane is in focus (selected). However, AccordionPane.selected property will be set to "True" once the AccordionPane is selected, and AccordionPane.selected stays as "True" even other dijit.layout.AccordionPane is selected. 
So in other words, if I have 3 AccordionPanes, after I clicked on all 3 of them, AccordionPane.selected property for all 3 of them are "True" now.
Is this a bug, or there is other ways to determine which AccordionPane is currently being selected (in focus)?
Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `dijit.layout.AccordionContainer` that contains all these three `dijit.layout.AccordionPane` to determine which one is currently selected.

You can use `dijit.layout.AccordionContainer`'s property `selectedChildWidget` to get current selected `dijit.layout.AccordionPane`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using AccordionContainer, but didn't know to use selectedChildWidget property to check.

Answer (score 1):

`AccordionPane`s are wrapped within an `AccordionContainer`. The `AccordionContainer` extends [`StackContainer` which uses Dojo's pub-sub communication channel](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/StackContainer.html) to advertise when a pane was selected. Subscribe to topic `[widgetId]-selectChild` to get notified every time when a new pane is selected. `[widgetId]` is the widget ID of the container element.

```
dojo.subscribe("[widgetId]-selectChild", function(pane){
    console.log("A new pane was selected:", pane);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too! While your suggestion is to get notified when it's selected, I was trying to find out which one is currently being selected, and I think I could do this by using onFocus().
cheers!